# UITextView Shadow Not Working

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, calayer, shadow

I am trying to get a UITextView's layer's shadow to work in a UITableView header.  I have a UIView that I am formatting everything in, and then setting the headerview equal to it.

```
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 450);
UIColor * baseColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed: 45/255.0
                                             green: 100/255.0
                                              blue: 150/255.0
                                             alpha: 1.0];

view.backgroundColor = baseColor;
...
UITextView * newCommentField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 230, 270,   120)];
newCommentField.text = @"New Comment";
newCommentField.tag = 3;
newCommentField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
newCommentField.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
newCommentField.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
newCommentField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
[view addSubview:newCommentField];
...
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;
```

Everything shows up properly in the view.  However, the shadow is not appearing.  I don't know what is going wrong here.  I have even tried modifying the layer's frame and making it the size of the comment field, bigger and the same size.

Comment: Whats the height of your header? isn't your newCommentField's height greater than header's?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally didn't copy that in somehow.  It is 450.  The newCommentField's height is less I think.

Comment: And why are you making you header height 450, when the full height of the iphone screen is 460?

Comment: I just want the user to be able to see the the top of the comments. Also it changes to 460 if the user is an admin and I didn't want the admin buttons to be below the screen.

Comment: Sorry I should be clear, it is above a tableview with comments in it.

Comment: try pullin the table cell down and see if the shadow exist?

Comment: I am trying to put the shadow on the textview not the tableview or tableview cell.

Comment: Just dynamic prototype cells using the normal method for formatting the cells, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way also... Create a view (eg. bgView) of same size as your textView and add that textView as a subView of bgView, which will be added as subView of you header view. Apply the shadow effect to the bgView instead.

```
UIView *bgView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 230, 270,   120)];
bgView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
bgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
bgView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
bgView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
bgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;

[bgView addSubview:newCommentField];

[view addSubview:bgView];
```

Comment: @Neo Do you know why we have to use that trick to add a shadow to a uitextview? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting background color for newCommentField. 
Try:

```
newCommentField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```